# Best way to generate unique Random number in Java

Tags: java, random, serial-number

I have to generate unique serial numbers for users consisting of 12 to 13 digits. I want to use random number generator in Java giving the system. Time in milliseconds as a seed to it. Please let me know about the best practice for doing so. What I did was like this

```java
Random serialNo = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println("serial number is "+serialNo);
```

Output came out as: `serial number is java.util.Random@13d8cc98`

Comment: Have you done a basic google search? Here is one possibility: https://mkyong.com/java/java-generate-random-integers-in-a-range
There are other similar questions on StackOverflow too

Comment: Yes sir, i had checked and my requirement is not for the range in the serial numbers. I just want to generate unique serial number of minimum 13 digits that is why i want to pass system time in milliseconds in it so that it can be unique too. i want to know the best practice for that.

Comment: If you just want a different 13 digits long number based on the system millis every time maybe you can just use the system millis and forget about pseudorandom generators.

Comment: Your question states "consisting of 12 to 13 digits" which implies a range.

Comment: @Javito This is unsafe if he wants to use it as an encryption key or anything related to cyber-security. Also, this would not work if he creates two or more *random* number in the same millisecond. And most importantly, it is just **not random** at all…

Comment: As @Wutong has mentioned. I have to maintain it unique for security purpose that is why i came uo with this requirement.

Comment: Using just the millis and using the first generated number with the millis as seed both have the same uniqueness. The millis are just the amount of milliseconds that have passed since January 1st 1970. If you use the same seed for a RNG, you will get the same "random" number every single time. If you want something more secure, you should probably use something a bit more complex, check out @Joop Eggen answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a random number generator using the current time as seed (as you did)

```
long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
Random rng = new Random​(seed);
```

Now, to get a number, you have to use the generator, `rng` is NOT a number.

```
long number = rng.nextLong();
```

According to the documentation, this will give you a pseudorandom number with 281.474.976.710.656 different possible values.

Now, to get a number with a maximum of 13 digits:

```
long number = rng.nextLong() % 10000000000000;
```

And to get a number with exactly 13 digits:

```
long number = (rng.nextLong() % 9000000000000) + 1000000000000;
```

Comment: Sir, as for your solution unique number will consist of 19 digits at minimum. But i just need the number having utmost 13 digits. So, what will be the scenario in that? Will the uniqueness be maintained in doing so?

Comment: You can always narrow down the result with the % operator, I'll edit my solution.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Of course, you can rely on the odds in some cases, but if some security is required, uniqueness should be verified against a list of the already existing numbers. The OP was very especific about how they wanted to obtain the number so I just responded to that, but I would not just use a simple random generator like that with that porpose.

Answer (score 4):

For a bit better algorithm pick SecureRandom.
You passed a seed to the random constructor. This will pick a fixed sequence with that number. A hacker knowing the approximate time of calling, might restrict the number of attempts. So another measure is not using the constructor and `nextLong` at the same spot.

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom​();
long n = random.nextLong();
```

A symmetric bit operation might help:

```
n ^= System.currentMillis();
```

However there is a unique number generation, the UUID, a unique 128 bits number, two longs. If you xor them (`^`) the number no longer is that unique, but might still be better having mentioned the circumstantial usage of random numbers.

```
UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
long n = id.getLeastSignificantBits() ^ id.getMostSignificantBits();
```

Comment: Sir, as you have used (^) operation and taken the least significant bits if "id". Please let me know for which variable you have suggested to take the most significant bit here?

Comment: id contains two longs (so 128 bits), and I do `getLeast ^ getMost`. Aha, I forgot `id.`

Comment: Thanks for your response sir. However, as you have provided two solutions 1.) by using secure random and performing bit operation,  2.) by performing the XOR between LSB and MSB of UUID.... Please suggest me which will be more useful in my scenario. Because i will trim it down upto the 15 digits and i want them to be unique.

Comment: Sir, if i will use secure random  with bitwise operation and then trip down the final value upto 14 digits then will it be unique?? because that is something i am looking forward to do now.

Comment: For 15 digits uniqueness should be checked I think. Use UUID definitely as it at least tackles _uniqueness_ and removes some worries. A positive value you can take a modulo `n %= 1_000_000_000_000_000L;` for 15 digits.

Comment: Thanks sir. One more thing sir as i have checked the output in the loop, i got to know that the number of digits are not coming as fixed like -7586517246683211893,
3637120480246133166, -737802708711737064 etc. Is it because of "-" or something. Please guide me. Because i have to remove this "-" and i want fixed digits.

Comment: Also sir, by using % also, i am getting 14 or 15 digits. My code is just.....** UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
long n = id.getLeastSignificantBits() ^ id.getMostSignificantBits();
n %= 1_000_000_000_000_000L;
System.out.println("number: "+n);  **
For example, now using this code i got three different digits as -93946215344033, 642990330944621, 86628130516587

Comment: Do not forget to the absolute value.

Comment: Exactly sir, at last i had used Math.abs(n); However, by using the absolute value "-" got removed but still there were differences in number of digits. for example: 1612734704191(13 digits)
590702397467966(15 digits)
15655531803746(14 digits)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248013/discussion-between-anshul-and-joop-eggen).

Answer (score 1):

First, import the Random class:

```java
import java.util.Random;
```

Then create an instance of this class, with the current milliseconds as its seed:

```java
Random rng = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

This line would generate an integer that can have up to 13 digits:

```java
long result = rng.nextLong() % 10000000000000;
```

This line would generate an integer that always have 13 digits:

```java
long result = rng.nextLong() % 9000000000000 + 1000000000000;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to generate Random numbers in java

1. java.util.Random class
   We can generate random numbers of types integers, float, double, long, booleans using this class.

Example :
//Random rand = new Random();
// rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(1000)

2. Math.random method : Can Generate Random Numbers of double type.
   random(), this method returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

Example :
Math.random());
//Gives output 0.15089348615777683

3. ThreadLocalRandom class
   This class is introduced in java 1.7 to generate random numbers of type integers, doubles, booleans etc

Example :

```
    //int random_int1 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt();
    // Print random integers
    //System.out.println("Random Integers: " + random_int1);
```